# Icosahedron particle system with three.js? Just getting squares?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am a newbie to three.js and am building a solar system where I need a particle system where the particles are icosahedrons. I have created a particle system from a tutorial using this function:

```
function createParticleSystem() {

    // The number of particles in a particle system is not easily changed.
    var particleCount = 2000;

    // Particles are just individual vertices in a geometry
    // Create the geometry that will hold all of the vertices
    var particles = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(1, 0);

    // Create the vertices and add them to the particles geometry
    for (var p = 0; p < particleCount; p++) {

        // This will create all the vertices in a range of -200 to 200 in all directions
        var x = Math.random() * 400 - 200;
        var y = Math.random() * 400 - 200;
        var z = Math.random() * 400 - 200;

        // Create the vertex
        var particle = new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z);

        // Add the vertex to the geometry
        particles.vertices.push(particle);
    }

    // Create the material that will be used to render each vertex of the geometry
    var particleMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial(
            {color: 0xffffff, 
             size: 4,
             shading: THREE.FlatShading,
             blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
             transparent: true,
            });

    var partMaterial2 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, shading: THREE.FlatShading, vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors, shininess: 0   } );

    // Create the particle system
    particleSystem = new THREE.Points(particles, particleMaterial);

    return particleSystem;  
}
```

And this creates particles at varying positions, however although I set the geometry to `THREE.IcosahedronGeometry` and attempted to change the material, the only thing I am able to create are flat white squares. If i change the material to `MeshPhongMaterial` as I have used previously, my scene will not render.

How can I make Icosahedron particles?

Comment: The particles are squares. If u want Icosahedron, do it

  `map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(
    "images/Icosahedron.png"
  ),`

Read it about particles : https://aerotwist.com/tutorials/creating-particles-with-three-js/

U take wrong way about particles

Comment: @Treize Cinq  Is "ParticleSystem" deprecated?  The link
http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Objects/ParticleSystem
gives "404 - not found"

Comment: @dcromley Nope, have a look here :    https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/css3d_sprites.html and here :  https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_custom_attributes_particles.html

Comment: @Treize Cinq  I can't get anything from that first example -- no errors -- no output.  I'll work on it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I realize this is late.)  The IcosahedronGeometry has vertices, but you don't normally set them individually.  You set the vertices of Points and Line.  I think everything else is a mesh.  (I hope someone else has better wording.)

To do points:

```
geometry = new THREE.Geometry(); 
material = new THREE.PointsMaterial( { color:0xffffff, size:1 } );
geometry.vertices.push( // your points get pushed
var object3d = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
scene.add(object3d);
```

To do line segments:

```
geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push( // your line ends get pushed
material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color:0xffffff } );
object3d = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
scene.add(object3d);
```

To do Icosahedrons, or any mesh:

```
for (var i1=0; i1<N; i1+=1) { 
  geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(1); 
  material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color:0xffffff, shading:THREE.FlatShading } );
  material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
  mesh= new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  mesh.position.set(x, y, z);
  scene.add(mesh);
}
```

Comment: do icosahedrons always use meshphongmaterial?

Comment: @skyguy I'm quite sure other materials can be used.  I'll have to experiment to see what CANNOT be used.